# How to mock methods in the below code in the .NET 6 using Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, .net-6.0, xunit.net

Below is **InvokeAsync** method which need to tested.

```
    public async Task<bool> InvokeAsync(Batch batch)
    {
        var refundRequests = await this.RefundRepository.GetsAsync(batch.RefundRequests.Select(x => x.Id));

        refundRequests.RemoveAll(x => x.Status != RefundRequestStatus.Approved);
        var distributions = await DistributionRepository.GetsAsync(refundRequests.Select(x => x.Distribution.Id));

        var bundles = await this.BundleRepository.GetsAsync(distributions.Select(x => x.BundleId));

        foreach (var getRefundRequest in refundRequests)
        {
            var distribution = distributions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == getRefundRequest.Distribution.Id);

            if (distribution?.BundleId != null)
            {
                var bundle = bundles.First(x => x.Id == distribution?.BundleId);

                Bundle result = await Reverse.InvokeAsync(getRefundRequest, distribution, bundle); //MOCK
            }
            getRefundRequest.Status = RefundRequestStatus.Closed;
            getRefundRequest.LastUpdatedBy = "Test User";

            bool isUpdated = await UpdateRefund.InvokeAsync(getRefundRequest); //MOCK
        }

        batch.Status = BatchStatus.Posted;
        batch.LastUpdatedBy = "Test User";
        var isSuccess = await UpdateBatch.InvokeAsync(batch); //MOCK

        return isSuccess;
    }
```

**Unit test method**

```
[Fact]
public async Task Post_Batch()
{
    foreach (var refundBatch in Factory.Batch.CreateRefundBatchesData())
    {
        var refundRequests = await this.RefundRequestRepository.GetsAsync(batch.RefundRequests.Select(x => x.Id));
        var distributions = await this.DistributionRepository.GetsAsync(refundRequests.Select(x => x.Distribution.Id));
        var bundles = await this.BundleRepository.GetsAsync(distributions.Select(x => x.BundleId));

        for (int i = 0; i < refundRequests.Count; i++)
        {
            var refundRequest = refundRequests[i];
            var bundle = bundles[i];
            var distribution = distributions[i];
            MockSetupReverse(refundRequest, distribution, bundle);
            MockSetupUpdateRefund(refundRequest);
        }

        MockSetupUpdateBatch(batch);

        //Act
        var postRefund = await UseCase.InvokeAsync(batch);

        //Assert
        postRefund.ShouldNotBeNull();
        postRefund.IsPosted.ShouldBeTrue();
    }
}
```

**MockSetup** methods

```
private void MockSetupReverse(RefundRequest refundRequest, Distribution distribution, Bundle bundle)
{
    this.MockReverse
        .Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(refundRequest, distribution, bundle))
        .Returns(async () => 
        {
            bundle.Status = BundleStatus.Closed;
            return await Task.Run(() => bundle); 
        });
}

private void MockSetupUpdateRefund(RefundRequest refundRequest)
{
    this.MockUpdateRefund
            .Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(refundRequest))
            .Returns(async () =>
            {
                refundRequest.Status = RefundRequestStatus.Closed;
                refundRequest.LastUpdatedBy = Factory.RefundRequest.TestUserName;
                return await Task.Run(() => true);
            });
}

private void MockSetupUpdateBatch(Batch batch)
{
    this.MockUpdateBatch
            .Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(batch))
            .Returns(async () =>
            {
                refundBatch.Status = BatchStatus.Posted;
                refundBatch.LastUpdatedBy = Factory.RefundRequest.TestUserName;
                return await Task.Run(() => true);
            });
}
```

The mocking of the **UpdateBatch** is **working** and returns **true** when the method is invoked. But, the mocking of the **Reverse** and **UpdateRefund** returns **false** when the respective method is invoked. Any thoughts?

Please let me know if more info is required to support the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `Setup` your mocks with a specific parameter, the `Returns` only applies when this specific parameter is used.

The reason `UpdateBatch` works is because you're using the same reference to the same `Batch` in both the mock and the class under test:

```
MockSetupUpdateBatch(batch);

//Act
var postRefund = await UseCase.InvokeAsync(batch); // <---- Same "batch"
```

When your test code is calling `RefundRequestRepository.GetsAsync` you probably get different results than when the tested class calls `GetsAsync`, so the setup is not relevant for the calls of the tested class and probably returns the default bool value (`false`).

For more information on how to mock correctly refer to [this GitHub page](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)